# Problems with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Writing a little programm on Python 3.
There is a rectangle and it has to bounce from walls(borders of a window)

```
check=False

from tkinter import*
rect_x=50#x0 of rect
rect_y=50#y0 of rect
rect_x1=rect_x+rect_x#x1 of rect
rect_y1=rect_y+rect_y#y1 of rect
rect_change_x=5#change X speed
rect_change_y=3#change Y speed
root=Tk()

while check==False:

    if rect_y > 450 or rect_y < 0:
        rect_change_y = rect_change_y * -1
    if rect_x > 650 or rect_x < 0:
        rect_change_x = rect_change_x * -1


    rect_x+=rect_change_x#changing x
    rect_y+=rect_change_y#changing y
    rect_x1+=rect_change_x#changing x1
    rect_y1+=rect_change_y#changing y1



    c=Canvas(root,bg='yellow',width=700,height=500)
    c.pack()
    rect=c.create_rectangle(rect_x,rect_y,rect_x1,rect_y1,fill='black')



root.mainloop()
```

I guessed,that everything is Ok,but when I run this programm nothing happens.Tkinter window is not appearing.
What's wrong with it,where i have a mistake?

Comment: To display something, you have to enter the eventloop. But everything you do is to run an infinite loop. Use async programming. Schedule the next paint with some timer.

Answer (score 1):

To display something, you have to enter the eventloop

The last line

```
root.mainloop()
```

does that. Until you call this line, nothing is drawn.
You do everything in a loop.

Use async programming. Schedule the next paint with some timer.

```
check=False

from tkinter import*
rect_x=50#x0 of rect
rect_y=50#y0 of rect
rect_x1=rect_x+rect_x#x1 of rect
rect_y1=rect_y+rect_y#y1 of rect
rect_change_x=5#change X speed
rect_change_y=3#change Y speed
root=Tk()

def paintloop():
    global check,rect_x,rect_y,rect_x1,rect_y1,rect_change_x,rect_change_y
    root.after(100, paintloop)
    if rect_y > 450 or rect_y < 0:
        rect_change_y = rect_change_y * -1
    if rect_x > 650 or rect_x < 0:
        rect_change_x = rect_change_x * -1
     ...


root.after(0,paintloop)
root.mainloop()
```

Some other notes: don't create a new canvas every time. Currently you create N canvas with the first frame, the next one is the second, and display them all below the previous one.
After you finish the while loop (never).

Comment: You don't really need to do `root.after(0, paintloop)` right before calling mainloop, you can just call `painloop()` directly. Calling it directly means the initial scene will be painted before the GUI appears, which might be preferable.